# Cannot scroll page in the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot scroll the page even if the content inside require to scroll it. The page is cut. http://medica.mastertools.net/. You can login (fake form just submit).

No `overflow:hidden` in the css. 
Is maybe due to the viewport that is not set?

Below the html code of the main page, I have used Bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
/>
<title><?=SITETITLE?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Medica" />
<meta name="description" content="Medica Webshop" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"  href="<?
=HTTPPATH?>css/print.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?
=HTTPPATH?>css/screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?
=HTTPPATH?
>css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?
=HTTPPATH?>css/styleNew.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="<?=HTTPPATH?
>js/library.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="<?=HTTPPATH?
>js/validation.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
   <?php $this->view('new/header'); ?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 align-self-center">
      <?=$main_content?>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <?=$right?>      
    </div>
  </div>




</div>

<div id ="bottom" class="fixed-bottom"> <?=$footer?> </div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"No overflow:hidden in the css"_ That would be incorrect. More importantly, you need to put a [mcve] in your question

Comment: I have linked the page, because the code is really complex

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `body` tag does have `overflow:hidden` set, on line 21 of screen.css. Change that to `overflow:auto` and you should be all set.

Comment: This site have a lot of unecessary `overflow` rules. This can become an mess if not done well.

Comment: I have set all the overflow to auto but still cannot scroll